# JobDispacter vs Android-job(Evernote)

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher, android-job

I have a query regarding which API to use for running background jobs for devices which are below 5.1(LOLLIPOP). As JobScheduler API supports only 5.1 and above devices. I wanted to implement a background job API for devices below 5.1. Any one who worked on this can give your valuable suggestions so that I can move according based on the answers.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at Service in Android? It is meant to do long running task in background but make sure that you spawn a separate thread for it as Service runs in main thread, otherwise use IntentService which is standard implementation of Service which has its own thread to schedule work to be done.

Comment: @mobiledev I have services and intent services to do that long running operations but it is about firing the jobs i'm interested in. Have you worked on any of these which I was mentioning in the question.

Comment: You may have to use AlarmManager along with IntentService in order to achieve it. I guess, you basically want to fire a job when certain condition is met for which you can use AlarmManager and IntentService.

Comment: @mobiledev I have implemented JobScheduler API for devices which are 5.1 and above. But for devices below 5.1 i'm looking for a library which does that rather writing my boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job). It did all the work for you of implementing all APIs.

> A utility library for Android to run jobs delayed in the background. Depending on the Android version either the `JobScheduler`, `GcmNetworkManager` or `AlarmManager` is getting used.